# How To Embed font-awesome CSS into DOM Scripting (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, font-awesome

Here, javascript, using DOM SCRIPTING, generates a last line for browser display that reads: "No Finds". Suppose I want to juxtapose an "iconic character" from font-awesome (fontawesome), eg, their smiley face, right after the word "Finds".

I tried wedging this string:

```
<i class = 'fa fa-smile-o'></i>
```

just after the words "No Finds", as follows, but that did not work.

This is code that works:

```
newrow = makeEle({ tag: "tr", dom: [makeEle({ tag: "td", id: "tdWhere", dom: [document.createTextNode("No Finds")] })] });
```

Here's my addition - that failed:

```
newrow = makeEle({ tag: "tr", dom: [makeEle({ tag: "td", id: "tdWhere", dom: [document.createTextNode("No Finds<i class = 'fa fa-smile-o'></i>")] })] });
```

How do I get CSS (of font-awesome) to bear influence here? I don't really understand how javascript and CSS interface, so I may be asking for the impossible.

---

The above was solved by correct coding as follows (thanks to Michal):

```
newrow = makeEle({ tag: "tr", dom: [ makeEle({ tag: "td", dom: [document.createTextNode(" No Finds "), makeEle({ tag: "i", className: "fa fa-frown-o" }) ] }) ] });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the font-awesome markup is HTML and not simply text, the `document.createTextNode` function won't work. So you have to use `makeEle` to make that `i` tag node. Here's what the code looks like (I split it out into multiple lines for readability):

```
newrow = makeEle({
  tag: "tr",
  dom: [
    makeEle({
      tag: "td",
      id: "tdWhere",
      dom: [
        document.createTextNode("No Finds"),
        makeEle({
          tag: "i",
          className: "fa fa-smile-o"
        })
      ]
    }),
  ]
});
```

Note the extra `makeEle` call inside of the `dom` array for the `td`.

See [here for a demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phxg8mLq/)

Comment: Tried your code Michal but it didn't work for me. Here is my makeEle code (that I inherited and can't say I understand it): IT MAY DISPLAY TERRIBLY BECAUSE OF THIS COMMENT EDITORfunction makeEle(p) {
 e = document.createElement(p.tag);
  if(p.id) e.id = p.id;
//   if(p.className) e.className = p.className;
  var a = p.attr||{}; for(var i in a) { e.setAttribute(i,a[i]); }
//   var s = p.style||{}; for(var i in s) { e.style[i] = s[i]; }
 var h = p.handler||{}; for(var i in h) { e[i] = h[i]; }
    var d = p.dom||[]; for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++) { e.appendChild(d[i]); }
 return e;
}

Comment: Alrighty, I updated my answer. It should work now! The change was to make `class` be `className`. Cheers!

Comment: Ah sorry - one last thing you need to fix. The line `if(p.className) e.className = p.className;` is commented out. You need to get rid of the `//` in front of that line to make it active code. See my jsfiddle for a working demo!

Comment: YES! THANKS!! Michal, what does that p stand for, that you had me uncomment?

Comment: The `p` is the variable representing the object that is passed into the `makeEle` function. So in the case of the `makeEle` call to create the `i` element, p is `{ tag: "i", className: "fa fa-smile-o" }`. That line you uncommented sets the className of the return value to the one passed in through `p`.

Comment: Sounds like this worked, then? Great! Please mark my answer as accepted :) And good luck in your future code development!

Comment: Michal, as per your help, I got through one obstacle. The same sort of problem, however, I cannot figure out, which I've added to the bottom half of the original question above (under the dashes-line). The second line of code seems to be where I mess up (rTitle = rTitle + ...). Can you help me with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set the class to `fa fa-smile-o`.

```
var i = document.createElement("i");
i.className = 'fa fa-smile-o';
```

Comment: @ruffy Please update your question, it's very difficult to read code from comments.